# What does it mean in linux scripts? #!/usr/bin/python -tt

Tags: python, linux, bash, interpreter

I know that in the begining of .sh bash scripts is

```
#!/bin/bash
```

which points to the command interpeter executable.

But during watching Google Python Class http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKTZoB2Vjuk I noticed that for python they use

```
#!/usr/bin/python -tt
```

. Surfing the Internet I also have found such styles of this notation:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
```

and even

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

.

So, I'm new with Python and I'm ordinary Linux user and I have a few questions about this "magic" line:

1. First of all, what is the right form of this line? and why?
2. What does -tt key means in #!/usr/bin/python -tt ?
3. What program is parsing this line in Linux?
4. What syntax of this line for any script?
5. Why this line is so necessary if each file have it's extension?
6. And what about that in each computer interpreter for some kind of scripts will be stored in different place than in another? And script couldn't be run.

It's really interesting to me.
What's this line? Why this line? How to write this line? Why in such a way?...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Question #1) The line is called a shebang, and there's no right form that works universally. e.g.

```
#!python
#!/usr/bin/python
#!/usr/local/bin/python
#!/usr/bin/python -t
```

are all valid/acceptable forms, but may not work on all systems:

`#!python` will work only if the python executable is somewhere in your shell's PATH

`#!/usr/bin/python` only works if the python binary is actually in /usr/bin

`#!/usr/local/bin/python` also only works if python is in /usr/local/bin

Question #2)

`#!/usr/bin/python -tt` is passing the `-tt` option to python, as if you'd done:

```
$ python -t somescript.py
```

at the shell prompt. You can pass arbitary command line arguments to the interpreter on the shebang line.

Question #3)

The line is interpreted by the OS kernel and the shell you're currently using. The stuff after the `#!` simply tells the OS which program should be fired up to "execute" the rest of the script.

Question #4)

The script syntax depends on the language you're using. E.g. a PHP shell script must take the form of

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
  ... php code here ...
```

A `#!/usr/bin/perl` perl script must use Perl syntax, etc... If you put PHP code with a Perl shebang, you'll just have Perl barf up the script with syntax errors, as PHP code is **NOT** perl code

Question #5)

Shebangs are for Unix systems, where file extensions were never really used to identify file types to the OS. A `.c` file was understood to be a C language source code file, but that's merely a convention. You could put a Bash shell script into a `.c` file, make it executable, and with the `#!/bin/bash` shebang, it would execute as a Bash script.

Determining executable types by file extension is more of a Windows thing.

Question #6)

That goes back the stuff in question #1 - if the shebang claims the interpreter is at some OTHER path than where it is, this particular script can't be executed until the shebang is fixed, or the interpreter is moved. Shebangs are very handy, but not infallible.

Thankfully, most interpreters are installed in fairly standard locations these days, so it'd be somewhat unusual to find (say) Perl installed at `/some/wonky/weird/path` instead of `/usr/bin`

Comment: you skipped the `#!/usr/bin/env python` alternative in your list of point 1. Some special reason?

Comment: woops, missed that one. `env` is a unix app that prints otu the current environment vars/values. on most shells, you can do `SOMEVAR=value name_of_app` to define an env var(s) that should be present within that apps environment. doing `/usr/bin/env python` just forces ALL current environment variables to be present in python's.

Comment: See shadyabhi's answer for "-tt".

Answer (score 7):

From the manpage:

> -t     Issue  a  warning  when  a source file mixes tabs and spaces
>   for indentation in a way that makes it depend on the worth of a tab
>   expressed in spaces.  Issue an
>                 error when the option is given twice.

1. The right form of the line is the one you want to use.
2. It's the interpreter that reads this line known as [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29). If you write a python script with first line as "#!/usr/bin/python" & invoke it using bash, it's the /bin/sh interpreter that reads first line and starts the proper interpreter.
3. It's a shebang. The syntax of feature consists of the character sequence #!, i.e. the number sign and an exclamation point character
4. File extensions are not relevant in linux *generally*. You can have a python script that doesn't have a .py extension.

For ex.

```
shadyabhi@archlinux ~ $ cat a 
print "Hello World" 
shadyabhi@archlinux ~ $ python2 a 
Hello World 
shadyabhi@archlinux ~ $
```

Even the shebangs are only necessary if you want to start a script using $./script as in this case you didn't mention the interpreter you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

1. #!/usr/bin/env python
2. issue errors about inconsistent tab usage
3. Kernel
4. #!/path_to_the_interpreter or /usr/bin/env
5. *nix does not check extensinon at all(except some DE could do that)
6. This is why you should use #!/usr/bin/env

More info at [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python` does not allow you pass the `-tt` option (or any other option) to the python interpreter.  See also [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/10454) and [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/10454).

Comment: @KeithThompson that is actually incorrect: using `#!/usr/bin/env python -tt` works and does exactly what is requested: runs the `python` interpreter found first in the `PATH` with the `-tt` option, followed by the script in question.

Comment: @JonathanCallen: Not on my system (Ubuntu 11.04); I get `/usr/bin/env: python -tt: No such file or directory`.  On Solaris 9, it does invoke the script with `python`, but it appears to ignore the `-tt`.  What system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The different paths are to where the python interpreter has been installed. Different flavours of Linux install it in different places.

Linux doesn't care for extensions its a Windows thing.

The bash session uses the line to call the correct interpreter for the script your running.

The different places to where the files are stored, called and used are all based on defined places where files should be and located by software. Dev for devices, home for user stored area, bin for programs. But as time has gone by, different systems require different locations.

I would suggest getting a book on Linux/Unix and learning the basics of the file system. It does help a lot.

Answer (score -2):

This is called a shebang.  It tells the system that it should pass the file as an argument to the specified program instead of trying to execute it per se.

> First of all, what is the right form of this line? and why?

The correct path is wherever your python interpreter is installed. The arguments (`-tt`) will depend on what you want. Some people insist on `#!/usr/bin/env` in case the interpreter happens to be elewhere.

> What does -tt key means in #!/usr/bin/python -tt ?

I don't use python, so someone else will have to answer this.

> When I launch any script in Linux (not exact Python script) what program parses and uses this line? I consider that it's not bash because even for bash scripts this line is needed.

I've heard (and am pretty sure) it's the kernel. Even if it were bash, it would need the line to tell bash it is supposed to be a script it should interpret instead of passing to another program. `/usr/bin/env` is a command that searches the `PATH` for the specified argument and passes the script through the program it finds.

> What syntax of this line for any script? And what's the name of interpeter that parses it?

The syntax is the same as a command line, `#!command arguments`, but `command` has to be an absolute path, the `PATH` doesn't get searched.

> Why this line is so necessary if each file have it's extension?

Extensions mean nothing in *nix. I could name a bash script `script.pl`, `script.exe`, or even `script` without an extension.  If the script has the right shebang line, it gets passed through the right interpreter, otherwise the kernel tries to execute it as an executable and fails.  The system doesn't know about extensions. They're a convention for users, nothing more.

> And what about that in each computer interpreter for some kind of scripts will be stored in different place than in another? And script couldn't be run.

If I understand this correctly, you're saying different systems / distributions keep the interpreters in different places (e.g. `/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/local/bin/python`), and asking how the system knows which to use?
The answer is, it uses the one which is at the absolute path you gave it. This is actually a slight problem with executable scripts, and the reason why `/usr/bin/env` has come into vogue. As I said, `env` searches the `PATH` for the correct interpreter, so as long as your system has a `/usr/bin/env`, you're set, you don't need to look up or guarantee the location of the interpreter.